# no matching function for call to in below program

Tags: c++

I am just working on a program to find topological order if possible But when I am executing the below program I am getting error
as no matching function call,I am not so good at oops concept , I mentioned in findOrder function 
a comment where I am getting the error

I was solving  this problem [course schedule](https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule-ii/)

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> findOrder(int n, vector<vector<int>>& pa) {
        vector<int> g[n];
        for(auto p : pa){
            int u = p[1],v = p[0];
            g[u].push_back(v);
        }
        vector<bool>visited(n,false);
        vector<bool>instack(n,false);
        vector<int>order;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(!visited[i]){
                if(!dfs(i,visited,instack,g,order))return {};//getting error here
            }
        }
        reverse(order.begin(),order.end());
        return order;




    }


    bool dfs(int x,vector<int> &visited,vector<int> &instack,vector<int> g[],vector<int>order){
        instack[x]=true;
        visited[x]=true;
        for(int i=0;i<g[x].size();i++){
            if(instack[g[x][i]]==true)return false;
            else if(!visited[g[x][i]] && !dfs(g[x][i],visited,instack,g))return false;
        }
        instack[x]=false;
        order.push_back(x);
        return true;
    }

};
```

Comment: Hint: vector<bool> and vector<int> are two different types.

Comment: _@user121_ Please remove all unrelated code and provide a [mcve] (including the exact verbatim error message) as required here.

Answer (score 4):

In the protoype of your function `dfs` you have defined the parameters `instack` and `visited` as `vector<int>`, but you are providing variables of type `vector<bool>` in the calling function.

The easiest way is probably to change:

```
bool dfs(int x,vector<int> &visited,vector<int> &instack,vector<int> g[],vector<int>order)
```

into

```
bool dfs(int x,vector<bool> &visited,vector<bool> &instack,vector<int> g[],vector<int>order)
```

This is happening because `vector` is a templated class and the implicit conversion of `vector<int>` to `vector<bool>` isn't defined.